gethostbyname_r is giving ip address in little endian format
I am trying to get my machine IP address using gethostbyname_r(). It should give the ip address in network byte order which is big endian. But I think I am getting the address in little endian format.
For example, if my machine IP address is 10.80.0.200, Big endian integer should be 173015240 ((10 * 256 * 256 * 256) + (80 * 256 * 256) + 0 + 200) and Little endian integer should be 3355463690 ((200 * 256 * 256 * 256) + 0 + (80 * 256) + 10) and I am always getting the value as 3355463690 (Little endian)
Below is my C++ program
   rc = gethostbyname_r(hostname_.c_str(),
                        &h, buf, sizeof(buf),
                        &result, &local_errno);

   if (rc) {
      std::cout << "Failed to get the ip" << std::endl;
      ipaddr_ = 0;
   }

   ipaddr_ = *reinterpret_cast<uint32_t *>(h.h_addr_list[0]);

Can some one please let me know why gethostbyname_r() is giving the IP address in little endian format where it is supposed to be big endian. Or doing reinterpret_cast is changing the endianness. But as per my knowledge reinterpret_cast won't change the endianness.
Note: My machine format is little endian.
import sys
sys.byteorder // 'little'


You're casting the pointer, not the data it points to, so it doesn't change anything. But deferencing the pointer interprets the data.

I think you normally use ntohl() when processing this data, rather than using the raw value.

Or you don't worry about the byte order, since all other functions that take an IP address expect it in the same order that this returns.

I need to worry about the byte order as I am sending this data to another machine and the contract between 2 machines is ip address is always Big Endian integer.

A [mre] should be posted.

You take four bytes that are in network order, and (mis)nterpret them as little-endian integer, via reinterpret_cast. E.g. 10 is in the leftmost byte (the byte at lowest address) - your little-endian CPU takes it as the least significant byte, not as the most significant as it is meant to be. If you want to see an "expected" number with your eyes, use ntohl. If you want to pass the number somewhere that expects the network order, just pass it around as is.

The IP address 10.80.0.200 corresponds to the integer
10×2563 + 80×2562 + 0×2561 + 200×2560
Note this is not a "big endian integer" nor a "little endian integer". There are no such things. It's just an integer. It equals 173015240 on a big endian machine, on a little endian machine, or on a 127 qubit quantum computer.
"Big endian" and "little endian" are integer storage formats. The little endian storage format means that the least significant byte is stored first (lowest address), and the most significant byte is stored last (highest address). The big endian storage format means just the opposite.
The integer 173015240, stored in the big-endian format, will have its most significant byte (which equals 10) stored first, and its least significant byte (which equals 200) stored last. On your little-endian machine, however, the first byte is the least significant one, so these four bytes, when interpreted as an integer, look like 3355463690.

All of the networking APIs produce and consume addresses in big-endian order, which means that they are stored in memory with the most-significant bytes at the lowest addresses.
You’re taking the address and attempting to interpret it as a uint32_t, which on your platform is little endian.
The bytes of your address are (in decimal, from lowest to highest memory address):
10 80 0 200

Interpreted as a little-endian number, this will be 200*256^3 + 80*256 + 10 = 3355463690.
If you want a string representation of the address, use inet_ntoa - it will save you from having to interpret the bytes yourself.
